# If $\int_Uf(x,z)dz$ and $\int_Ug(z,y)dz$ are finite, is $\int_Uf(x,z)g(z,y)dz$ finite for all $x,y\in U$?

Tags: calculus

> If $\int_Uf(x,z)dz$ and $\int_Ug(z,y)dz$ are finite, is $\int_Uf(x,z)g(z,y)dz$ finite for all $x,y\in U$?

At first I tried using the schwartz's inequality, but didn't reach anywhere. Any help on this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to post an answer to this unless you tell us what $U$ is. But the answer definitely is NO. The variables $x$ and $y$ are redundant.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Does the fact that we are dealing with a compact space  or $U$ a bounded set change the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
\begin{align}
f(x, z) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{|z|}} \ \text{ and } \ \ g(z, y) = \frac{y}{\sqrt{|z|}}
\end{align}
and $U=[-1, 1]$. Observe
\begin{align}
\int^1_{-1} f(x, z)\ dz = 4x \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \int^1_{-1} g(z, y)\ dz = 4y
\end{align}
but
\begin{align}
\int^1_{-1} \frac{xy}{|z|}\ dz = \infty. 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If $U=[0,1]$ an $f(x,z)=g(z,y) =\frac 1 {\sqrt z}$ for $z \neq 0$, $f(x,z)=g(z,y) =0$ for $z=0$, then  $f$ and $g$ are integrable on $U$ but $fg$ is not.